# Can the nested conditional expectation $E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}$ be simplified?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have two real-valued random-variables $X$ and $Y$.

I am interested in simplifying the following expression (assuming it even makes sense to write):
$$
E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}
$$

My intuition is that since $E[X|Y]$ is just the first moment of the distribution $p(x|y)$, its value is fixed for a fixed $y$ regardless of any "later conditioning" on $X$. I.e. my instinct was,
$$
E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]} \overset{?}{=} E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\big{]} = E[X]
$$
However, expanding the integrals leads to something that I cannot seem to reduce.

By definition we have,
$$
E[X|Y] := \int_\mathbb{R} x p(x|Y) dx
$$

The "Law of the Unconscious Statistician" provides,
$$
E[f(Y)|X] = \int_\mathbb{R} f(y) p(y|X) dy
$$

Letting $f(Y) := E[X|Y]$ we have,
\begin{align}
E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]} &= \int_\mathbb{R} \Big{(}\int_\mathbb{R} x p(x|Y) dx \Big{)} p(y|X) dy\\[6pt]
&= \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} x p(x|Y) p(y|X) dxdy\\
\end{align}

There is definitely some weirdness in these expressions coming from the mixing of (uppercase) random-variables and (lowercase) variables-of-integration, which makes me wonder whether $E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}$ is even a meaningful expression. If the notation here is misleading and/or the root of the problem, please clarify how I should be writing and thinking of this.

**Recap: If the expression $E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}$ is meaningful, how can it be simplified? If it's nonsense, why?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it can be simplified, but I'm not sure. I think it's meaningful though, based on considering simple examples like $0<X<1$ and $2<Y<3$, uniformly distributed; or slightly more complicated like $Y<X<Y+1$ and $0<Y<2$, again with uniform distribution.

Comment: It is meaningful but it cannot be simplified.  It is instructive to see what happens in the cases when $X$ is independent of $Y$ or $X$ is measurable w.r.t.  $Y$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Worth noting here that my original instinct was a misapplication of the idea that $E[X|Y]$ is *conditionally independent* of $X$ *given $Y$*. It is not unconditionally independent of $X$ unless $Y$ is independent of $X$, in which case $E\big{[}E[X | Y] \big{|} X\big{]} \overset{X \perp Y}{=} E[X]$.

Comment: By definition $E(X|Y)$ is a function of $Y$. That is $E(X|Y)=g(Y)$, so $E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}=E(g(Y)|X)$ and depend on joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ varied. For example if they are independent $E\big{[}E[X \vert Y]\ \big{\vert}\ X\big{]}=E(g(Y)|X)=E(g(Y))=E(E(X|Y))=E(X)$.